# ASP.Net Membership Password recovery

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

**Current state of Application**
We got a huge user base currently and we had requiresUniqueEmail="false" setting from day one bcse business required such.
So our password recovery was done via UserName.

**Issue/Problem**
Suddenly the business wants the password recovery to be done either by Username or Email. But bcse we never had unique emails in the system (in few cases no email), we are having quite a few duplicate emails in the system. For example, xyz@xyz.com is assigned to 10 different usernames.

How can I tackle this situation in best possible way?
I was thinking along the lines, if a user selects by email, I will go ahead and send all the usernames which are associated with this email. Is that a good option?

Would love to have more ideas on this. I am sure someone should have had this sort of issue before.

Comment: "I was thinking along the lines, if a user selects by email, I will go ahead and send all the usernames which are associated with this email. Is that a good option?" Is it a good option to let a user activate password recovery for a different user's account? No. It is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

When accounts were set up did it send out a validation email to ensure people only subscribed using email addresses they owned? If so then you could send out all username's safe in the knowledge the owner of the email created them. If you didn't require validation then possibly anyone could get the email and read someone else's account.

Comment: Basically we will be searching the user in our database with the supplied email address (during password recovery) and then send the email about the credentials for the username to the supplied email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use email to narrow down to a single username recovery. For example:

```
Given a set of 10 usernames with the same email "email@domain.com"
When  I click "Recover Password By Email"
And   I enter "email@domain.com"
Then  I should see the message "select which username you want to recover"
And   I should see a list of the 10 usernames

When  I click on the username "username1"
Then  I should receive a password recovery email for the "username1" account 
      at the "email@domain.com" address
```

This way, you're still doing recovery by username, but only when the email has more than 1 username match.

I don't like the idea of sending the password recovery to all usernames. The user may have only forgotten one password.

Comment: Letting the user choose whose password to recover is *still* kind of a problem, though, isn't it?